# How to change the label of shared App bar in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Im developing an windows phone 8.1 app. I have used shared app bar  across the pages. At some point of time, I need to change the label or the icon of the global app bar. Is this possible?

your thoughts will be helpful.

Comment: how did you implement the shared appbar?

Comment: @IgorKulman I have implemented shred app bar following this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150604.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public MainPage()
```

{
    this.InitializeComponent();

```
Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
}

void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
CommandBar bottomCommandBar = this.BottomAppBar as CommandBar;
AppBarButton appbarButton_0 = bottomCommandBar.PrimaryCommands[0] as AppBarButton;
appbarButton_0.Label = "settings";
appbarButton_0.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Setting);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*BottomAppBar* at WP8.1 is [CommandBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn279427), there you will find [PrimaryCommands property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.commandbar.primarycommands), in which you probably have [AppBarButtons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbarbutton). If you want to change for example a *Label* (*Icon* or anything else), you should be able to do it like this:

```
// change the label of the first button
((BottomAppBar as CommandBar).PrimaryCommands[0] as AppBarButton).Label = "New Label";
```

If you want to change AppBarButton's parameters often, to make it easier, you can write a simple extension method:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Get AppBarButton of AppBar - extension method
/// </summary>
/// <param name="index">index of target AppBarButton</param>
/// <returns>AppBarButton of desired index</returns>
public static AppBarButton PButton(this AppBar appBar, int index) { return (appBar as CommandBar).PrimaryCommands[index] as AppBarButton; }
```

Of course it's the same as above, but makes little easier to use:

```
BottomAppBar.PButton(0).Label = "New label";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store your app bar in Resources than you can access it through the following code:

```
var commandBar = Application.Current.Resources["YouResourceKeyForAppBar"] as AppBar;
```

Now you have a reference to it and you can modify items inside it. If you implemented SharedApp in another way, please edit your question and tell more information about it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I can suggest an alternate solution thanks to the 8.1 libraries in the [Windows.UI.ViewManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.aspx) namespace namely the [StatusBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.statusbar.aspx) and the [ApplicationView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.aspx)'s Title

It won't help out this situation, but might make things simpler for another who is looking at this post.

```
var titleName = "TITLE";

var statusBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
statusBar.ProgressIndicator.Text = titleName;

var applicationView = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
applicationView.Title = titleName;
```

Then to show and hide, control with:

```
await statusBar.ProgressIndicator.ShowAsync();
await statusBar.ProgressIndicator.HideAsync();
```

Unfortunately, the only thing you'll be able to set up here is Title. I don't think you can set a custom Style to the StatusBar.