# WP 8.1 BarButton Icon changing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, appbar, commandbar

I'm just starting to learn C# and WP platform and i find it really hard to do some easy things, like changing a button icon, etc.

I've got a Command Bar and a AppBarButton created in XAML.

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar MinHeight="60">
        <AppBarButton x:Name="Command_BarButton" Icon="AllApps" 
                      Label="Seletie"
                      Click="AppBar_Select"/>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

I would like to change the AppBarButton icon programatically in C# to another prexistent icon, like the Trash icon. How can i do this ?

```
Command_BarButton.Label = "Delete";
Command_BarButton.Icon = ?
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26034268/2681948), maybe It will help.

Answer (score 2):

I knew it would be very easy to change the AppBarButton Icon at runtime.

This is how:

```
        Command_BarButton.Label = "Delete";
        Command_BarButton.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Delete);
```

Thanks to this [link](https://ibraheemosama.wordpress.com/2013/11/09/changing-appbarbutton-icon-on-run-time-in-windows-8-windows-8-1/)

Answer (score 1):

to change Icon from code behind try this

```
ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();

ApplicationBarIconButton button1 = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
button1.IconUri = new Uri("/Images/play.png", UriKind.Relative);
button1.Text = "play";
ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(button1);
```

[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394044%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

this shuold help

```
<AppBarButton Label="BitmapIcon" Click="AppBarButton_Click">
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <BitmapIcon UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/globe.png"/>
    </AppBarButton.Icon>
</AppBarButton>
```

[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj662743.aspx)

Comment: I want when the user taps on the bar button with the icon AllApps to change in the Trash/Delete icon.

Comment: than all you need to do is name your button with `x:Name` and than in codebehind create new BitmapIcon and asign it to AppBarButton.Icon

Comment: That's my real problem. How can i create a BitmapIcon with a trash icon ?

Comment: all you need is image, than add it to your `Assets` folder and set it property of `BitmapIcon` as i suggest in first answer under your question